# Interfacing with HTML elements in UIWebView from Obj-C: How to get, keep and use a reference

Tags: ios, uiwebview

If I have x,y coordinates, I can access the contents of an HTML element like this:

```
    location = [aTouch locationInView:myWebView];
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).innerHTML", location.x, location.y];
    NSString *text = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

However, I can't keep a reference for accessing it later:

```
    NSString *js2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f)", location.x, location.y];
    NSString *tagName = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js2];
```

...at least not unless the element has a name, and I don't have control over the HTML, so I can't just add it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get a pointer to DOM element or something like that. The only way to interface with the HTML itself is to use the Javascript API.

So you will need to store ID's/class names of elements or just look them up every time using DOM traversal.

I think I would inject some Javascript into the page to do the heavy lifting and call that API using the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method.

Comment: Edit: Never mind (http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview)